# Saving/Loading Unity game via database

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've done serialization(.dat file) and playerprefs, it works on the webGL build, but i have the game on a website and it calls words from a database , can i save the game data to a table and call the the data when the user wants to load the saved game? My lecturer wants it to work like this - when a person logs into the website the game displays, but the game data must only load according to that persons account

Answer (score 1):

Unity doesn't provide anything like PlayerPrefs that works on top of client/server architecture.

You'll need to implement it for yourself and there is lots of ways to go for this (websockets, webservices, etc...)

A good start point to understand what are you trying to do is provided on unity's wiki with an [online hightscores](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores) example. This works as a web application where you have PHP on server side and Unity as client using WWW class to communicate with server.

If you understand about RESTfull and WebSockets you can approach to implement a better solution than this example or find something on unity's [store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/online).